# Sharepoint- Find Document Libraries That User Has Write Access

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have a lot of document libraries, every document library can be viewed by all the user groups but only specific user groups can upload document to a document library, and all the users belong to at least one group.

What I need to do is, find the document libraries that the current user can upload a file, I want to use Sharepoint web services, I found Permissions.asmx GetPermissionCollection method,  but I dont want the site level permissions or a list I need permissions on a document library, so far I couldnt succeed.

Any idea would be more than welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A document library is a kind of list. You can use GetPermissionCollection on it.

Edit, added the following:

If you don't get what you need from the default Web Services, I suggest writing your own. It will run in your farm (alongside the built-in ones), so will have full access to the "normal" API and you can export the exact method you need.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, the other thing is: 

Every document library has folders and every folder has the same permission structure that some groups have write access on specific folders in a document library. 

How can I get the folders that the user has write access? Any idea? 

Thanks

Comment: This article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/spwslimits_1.aspx?fid=1563600&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick mentions that one is unable to get the permission of a list item, but doesn't say anything about folders. Have you tried giving the method a path to a folder to see if it answers correctly ?

Comment: I tried giving the folder path but I am having "Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException" exception. And it is not very descriptive exception :( 
Still no solution, I appreciate any idea. 

Thanks